# How does this user have 154 rep?

Tags: bug

https://stackoverflow.com/users/129899/eco-bach

154 rep. 425 questions (several high voted), 44 answers (top answer would yield 150 rep alone).

How is this even possible?

Comment: I just saw the bounties. Ugh.

Answer (score 2):

By spending much of the reputation on [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129899/eco-bach?tab=bounties&sort=offered).

Answer (score 2):

The user has offered [3150 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/users/129899/eco-bach?tab=bounties&sort=offered) in the form of bounties.